# What kind of project we should use Flutter, React Native or Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flutter

Now we have Flutter and React Native for Cross-Platform. Both of them very awesome. But we have many projects or products. I want to know.
When we should use Flutter and Why?
When we should use React Native and Why?
It same question for Native

Comment: This quesiton is too hard to answer, because it will be very opinion based, just FYI :)

Comment: Just discuss, I think someone have the same question with me. We need people who have a rich experience can talk something

Comment: Well that is kind of the problem with stackoverflow, that is supposed to give you a do this kind of answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Flutter and React Native are the two leading market players.

When it comes to developing desktop apps with Flutter, the API is still in the development stage. Google is working on extending Flutter to support desktop as a target environment, allowing developers to create macOS, Windows, and Linux applications with the technology.

Flutter for Web is currently available as a technical preview only.

For Mobile development, I think you should go with React Native, It has big community support.

Comment: Yes React Native has big community support and It's stable. I working with it. But when I visit Flutter showcase and try download Reflectly. It's amazing. I don't know how create animation like that on React Native 
- Flutter showcase: https://flutter.dev/showcase
- React Native showcase: https://reactnative.dev/showcase

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I think React-native is a better solution.

- It's stable now.
- There's a framework to make web also.
- It's javascript. If you want to go to web, learning Angular is a much more easier.
- A lot of frameworks and huge community.
- Even in the future you learn back-end (nodeJS) is much more easier to you.
- Love game ? Unity also use javascript.

Comment: Yes React Native map with Web Developer because It using javascript. But I want to focus Mobile development

Comment: Yes. another reason is you can code game with Unity using javascript :)